# 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

Tags: javascript, angular

hello there I have problem with this cod in angular 4

when I want type a number i face to this error 
'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40nS7.png)

Comment: Don't post images, post code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are declaring variable inside the constructor/function then you must prefix the variable declaration with `let` keyword.

```
constructor() {
  // let keyword is required
  let age: number = 36;
}
```

However, if you are declaring variable as a class member `let` keyword is not allowed.

```
export class AppComponent  {

  // let keyword is illegal
  age: number = 36;

  constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add "let" before age

```
let num:number = 35
```